# Random Number Order in C++ using <random>

Tags: c++, c++11, random, operator-precedence

I have the following code, that I wrote to test a part of a larger program :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  mt19937_64 Generator(12187) ;
  mt19937_64 Generator2(12187) ;
  uniform_int_distribution<int> D1(1,6) ;

  cout << D1(Generator) << " " ;
  cout << D1(Generator) << " " << D1(Generator) << endl ;
  cout << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << endl ;

  ofstream g1("g1.dat") ;
  g1 << Generator ;
  g1.close() ;
  ofstream g2("g2.dat") ;
  g2 << Generator2 ;
  g2.close() ;
}
```

The two generators are seeded with the same value, and therefore I expected the second row in the output to be identical to the first one. Instead, the output is

```
1 1 3
1 3 1
```

The state of the two generators as printed in the `*.dat` files is the same. I was wondering if there might be some hidden multi-threading in the random number generation causing the order mismatch.

I compiled with `g++` version 5.3.0, on Linux, with the flag `-std=c++11`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: In addition to the order-of-arguments answers you've gotten, keep in mind that distributions sometimes have internal states, so calling the distribution's `operator()` several times can leave it in a different state from a fresh copy. However, that's almost certainly not the case here; there's no compelling reason for `uniform_int_distrubution` to do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sadly, many universities still teach students to default to `endl` and never cover why it is less efficient than a plain '\n'. (I only learned that it was even an issue once I started browsing C++ questions on StackOverflow.)

Comment: @PeteBecker Premature optimization. For most purposes, the inefficiency of `endl` is totally negligible.

Comment: @Barmar - premature pessimization. There's no reason to do things that aren't needed when there's something just as simple that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`x << y` is syntactic sugar for a function call to `operator<<(x, y)`.

You will remember that the c++ standard places no restriction on the order of evaluation of the arguments of a function call.

So the compiler is free to emit code that computes x first or y first.

From the standard: §5 note 2:

> Operators can be overloaded, that is, given meaning when applied to expressions of class type (Clause
>   9) or enumeration type (7.2). **Uses of overloaded operators are transformed into function calls as described
>   in 13.5**. Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax specified in Clause 5, but the requirements of
>   operand type, value category, **and evaluation order are replaced by the rules for function call**.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you say applies here, isn't it more like `<<(a, <<(b, <<(c, d)))` ? Such that `<<(c, d)` has to be evaluated first?

Comment: @alain:  `<<(c, d)` has to be evaluated before any other `<<`, but a, b, c, d can be evaluated in any order (and the results saved).

Answer (score 36):

That's because the order of evaluation of this line

```
cout << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << endl ;
```

is not what you think.

You can test it with this:

```
int f() {
  static int i = 0;
  return i++;
}

int main() {
  cout << f() << " " << f() << " " << f() << endl ;
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `2 1 0`

---

The order is not specified by the C++ standard, so the order could be different on other compilers, please see Richard Hodges' answer.

Comment: That's what I missed!

Comment: @AviGinsburg:  Beware that when alain says "Output `2 1 0`" that's the output he gets on his machine with his compiler this time.  Any of the six possible orderings are permitted (although most systems will produce either `2 1 0` or `0 1 2`).

Comment: @alain,  No.  `cout << f() << g();` is `operator<<( operator<<( cout, f() ), g() )`.  It is clear that the first call to << has to happen before the second (because the result of the first is an argument to the second).  There is *no ordering* between the calls to `f` and `g`.  The compiler is entirely at liberty to call them both before any call to '<<' and in either order.

Comment: NP.  It's difficult to get your head round.  (I prefer the C# approach of standardizing the order things are evaluated.)

Answer (score 5):

A slight change to the program reveals what happens:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  mt19937_64 Generator(12187) ;
  mt19937_64 Generator2(12187) ;
  uniform_int_distribution<int> D1(1,100) ;

  cout << D1(Generator) << " " ;
  cout << D1(Generator) << " " ;
  cout << D1(Generator) << endl ;
  cout << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << " " << D1(Generator2) << endl ;
}
```

Output:

```
4 48 12
12 48 4
```

So your Generators produce equal results - but the order the arguments of your cout-line are calculated in different order.

Try it online:
http://ideone.com/rsoqDe

Comment: How does this demonstrate anything different/more from/than the OPs code?

Comment: @Yakk the are permuted just as in the OPs code. And just as the OPs code it does not proove that the random 48 is the same as the other random 48. It could be completely different sequences

Comment: @tobi303 True, there is roughly a 1 in 100000 chance that the values are coincidentally identical.  Wait, what?  (In the OP's code, there was 1 3 1 and 1 1 3 -- realizing that the two 1s where also permuted was harder to tell)

Answer (score 4):

These lines

```
  cout << D1(Generator) << " " ;

  cout << D1(Generator) << " "
       << D1(Generator) << endl ;

  cout << D1(Generator2) << " "
       << D1(Generator2) << " "
       << D1(Generator2) << endl ;
```

because `D1()` returns an int, for which `ostream::operator<<()` has an overload, are effectively calling (excluding `endl`)

```
cout.operator<<(D1(Generator));

cout.operator<<(D1(Generator))
    .operator<<(D1(Generator));

cout.operator<<(D1(Generator2))
    .operator<<(D1(Generator2))
    .operator<<(D1(Generator2));
```

Now, the standard has this to say,

> #### § 5.2.2 [4]
>
> When a function is called, each parameter shall
>   be initialized with its corresponding argument.
>
> **[ Note: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other — end note ]**
>
> If the function is a non-static
>   member function, the this parameter of the function shall be
>   initialized with a pointer to the object of the call

So let's break down the preceding expression

```
cout.operator<<(a())  // #1
    .operator<<(b())  // #2
    .operator<<(c()); // #3
```

To illustrate the construction of the `this` pointer, these are conceptually equivalent to (omitting `ostream::` for brevity):

```
operator<<(           // #1
  &operator<<(        // #2
    &operator<<(      // #3
      &cout,
      a()
    ),                // end #3
    b()
  ),                  // end #2
  c()
);                    // end #1
```

Now let's look at the top-level call. Which do we evaluate first, `#2`, or `c()`? Since, as emphasized in the quote, the order is indeterminate, then we don't know—and this is true recursively: even if we evaluated `#2`, we would still face the question of whether to evaluate its internal `#3` or `b()`.

So that hopefully explains what's going on here more clearly.